# Heroku Cloudinary addon vs cloudinary.com. What's the difference?

Tags: heroku, cloudinary

Heroku Cloudinary addon vs cloudinary.com.

What's the difference?

1. https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary
2. https://cloudinary.com/pricing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku plans utilise the classic/legacy Cloudinary plans where the quotas (Transformations, Storage and Bandwidth) are separate.

The new Cloudinary plans are based on credits. This is where any of the 3 quotas, Transformation, Storage and Bandwidth consume a shared pool of Credits. 1 credit equals 1,000 Transformations / 1GB Storage / 1GB Bandwidth.

For example, the Free plan allocates 25 available Credits. It means you can use these 25 credits in any combination between the three quotas as long it totals 25. You can use 5,000 Transformations, 10GB of Storage and 10GB of Bandwidth.

Alternatively, you can use 2,000 Transformations, 20GB of Storage and 3GB of Bandwidth. Or any combination in between the three quotas as long as it adds up to 25 Credits.

Credit based pricing offers more flexibility as they allow you to utilise the entire plan regardless of whether you're using more Transformations/Storage/Bandwidth. On the legacy plans, if you reach the limit of one quota but don't use much of the other two you will still need to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any difference other than the plans?

Comment: No other differences apart from the plans. You can also register a Cloudinary account directly and use it in your Heroku app or register with Heroku and later on also enable direct access or even move to direct Cloudinary access only.